# Why does PHP rand() is throwing 2 different values in chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

Can someone tell me why is chrome picking up 2 different values ??

I used like this

```
$rand = rand(1,10);
```

and i used the same value in the form as a hidden value

```
<input type='hidden' name='key' id='key' value=<?php echo $rand ?> />
```

when i echo the $rand and see the view source, i found the two values are different

This happens only in chrome ??

Try this example please

```
echo $rand = rand(9999,99999);
mysql_query("update <table> set enc_code='$rand'");
```

tell me if you're getting the same echoed value updating to the table ??

Thanks

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else. PHP executes on the same environment (your server) regardless of what browser you are using.

Comment: This is impossible. PHP is a server side language, so it happens in every browser or does not happen at all

Comment: It's because when you go to view source, Chrome reloads the page, and re-runs your PHP code.

Comment: When you use “view source” Chrome actually requests the page from the server again. Use developer tools instead to find the current value of your input field if you need to check it.

Comment: damn, why does this question got a -1. I know PHP is a server side script

Comment: right click and select inspect element to view value

Comment: I want to generate a random number and send that to the JS file, when i use console.log and echo...both the values are different. How can i acheive this ??

Comment: I quite dont understand... you are trying to see that value for debugging, or do you have problem in "real life" ?

Comment: Okay Martin, here it is. Try this sample
$rand = rand(1,10);
try to update this value to a sample table and check if you can post the same rand value in chrome or not ??

Answer (score 7):

Because Chrome probably refresh page, if you show its source. Firefox takes actual page and show its source.

Comment: indeed, that's exactly what Chrome does, which is even more annoying when dealing with POST requests.

Comment: thanks Tom, this is what my main issue is. I'm using the same random value in the JS and the value doesn't match. So how can i do this ??

Comment: If it's only for debugging and that problem is annoying you then use Firefox instead.

Answer (score 0):

OMG, with 2 hours of effort. I got the solution for the above query

I activated the extension **Firebug lite for Google Chrome**, this stupid extension is refreshing the browser and updating a new value to the database.

Finally, i fixed that.
This may be helpful for anyone in future...

thanks to all
Cheers

Comment: You should add this info to your OP, accept Martin Perry's answer, and delete this one.